# Best floating point solution for bash script?

Tags: linux, bash, bash-scripting, bc

I use bash calculator for floating point calculations and I have to use input redirection and backtick (`) symbol in scripts.

As normal bracket `$[math operation]` and expr doesn't support float calculation.
Is there any other way to do float calculation directly instead of using bc in script.
I don't like unnecessary input redirection and backtick (`) symbol for scripts.

```
#!/bin/bash
x=5
y=6
z=3.3
result=`bc <<end
scale=3
temp_divide=($x / $y)
temp_divide * $z
end`
echo "final result is $result"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bash doesn't support floating point arithmetics, so you are stuck with using bc for that. You could use self-written helper functions similar to [`float_eval`](http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/floating-point-math-bash), which makes using bc as an inline calculator a little bit easier.

If you don't have to use bash, you could also consider using [zsh](http://www.zsh.org/), which [supports floating point operations.](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Arithmetic-Evaluation.html) Example:

```
evnu@centraldogma ~ 
% ((val = 1.0))
evnu@centraldogma ~ 
% ((val = 2.2))
evnu@centraldogma ~ 
% echo $val
2.2000000000
evnu@centraldogma ~ 
% ((val += 2.2))
evnu@centraldogma ~ 
% echo $val
4.4000000000
```